# If I take limit, the strict inequality may become equal.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Suppose $$x \lt 1+\frac{1}{n} \;\; \forall n\in \Bbb N$$

If I let $n\to \infty$, I get $$x \le 1$$

But I am wondering the reason why $\lt$ should turned to $\le$ ?

This just an example in my analysis class, and this one is simple that $x$ can be $1$. But I want to know why if I take a limit to the strict inequality ,it becomes weaker. It looks simple but I have no idea to prove it.

Thanks for someone helping me.

Comment: If $x<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $x\le0$

Comment: Take $x=1$ to see that strict inequality cannot hold.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Claim:$x\lt \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon \gt 0$, then $x\le0$.

If not, $x\gt 0$, so $x \lt x$ which is a contradiction. Hence, $x\le 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x<a_n\,\forall n\in\Bbb N$ is equivalent to saying that $\{a_n-x\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a positive sequence. Is it true that limit of a strictly positive sequence is strictly positive always??

Comment: e.g. $1-\frac{1}{n}\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$, so $\{ 1-\frac{1}{n}-1 \}_{n\in \Bbb N}=\{\frac{1}{n} \}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to 0 which is not positive.

Comment: @StevenLu, $1-\dfrac1n-1=-\dfrac1n$.

Comment: Is it clear to you now why strict inequality may not hold in limiting case??