# What happens if I replace $\ge$ by $\gt$ in limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_\limits{x \to a}f(x)=L \ and \lim_\limits{x \to a}g(x)=K \ and  \ f(x) \ge g(x) \implies L\ge K$

What if I replace $\ge$ with $\gt$? Would it still be valid?

If no I'm looking for an example that would hold true for this.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try to find an example where $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$, but $\lim f(x) = \lim g(x)$.  It should be easy.

Comment: Hint: Strict inequality $>$ implies weak inequality $\geq$ but the opposite is not true. Take a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723347/if-i-take-limit-the-strict-inequality-may-become-equal

Comment: Alt. hint: what happens if $K=L$ and $g(x)=K$ is a constant function?

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to include the case of *equality* whenever you take limits on both sides of an inequality, regardless of whether the inequality is $>$ or $≥$.

Formally, for any $x$ in a deleted neighborhood of $a$,$$\left[f(x)> g(x) \right] \vee \left[f(x)≥g(x) \right] \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) ≥ \lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x)$$